# Is it "a spyglass TO the past" or "a spyglass INTO the past"

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to use the phrase *XYZ as a spyglass (in)to the past.* as title for a publication on a scientific method that allows me to infer knowledge about the past from data available now. E.g., the comparison of two contemporary bacteria allows us to infer likely features of their ancestor, which cannot be investigated as it's extinct.

Would *into* or *to* be the correct word here, and maybe more importantly: why?

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=window+into+the+past%2Cwindow+to+the+past&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwindow%20into%20the%20past%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwindow%20to%20the%20past%3B%2Cc0), ***into*** is more common. But they're both perfectly valid and mean the same thing.

Comment: so **into** seems to be the better choice, thanks for that. I'd still be interested in a grammatical rule that justifies this choice or maybe shows that one of the two is incorrect even though it's used.

Comment: May I suggest _XYZ as a window into the past_ instead? Spyglass sounds strange in this context.

Comment: I know that the common phrase uses _window_ (also see the NGram by @FumbleFingers). I wanted to use spyglass as I'm referring to a method that allows us to look millions of years back. I want to stress the length of this time period by the long-distance view a spyglass provides (in contrast to the short-ranged view out of a window). Does that sound reasonable enough to justify the unusual word? Besides, the grammatical question remains ;)

Comment: There's no issue of "grammar" here - like I said, both prepositions are effectively equivalent. But the [*single written instance with **spyglass***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spyglass+into+the+past%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) uses ***into***, as do 219 of the total 225 instances of ***telescope** to/into the past*. Personally, I think ***into*** is best because you *look/peer **into*** optical devices like that. I would note that ***spyglass*** is a rather "dated" word today, but that's no reason why you can't use it if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

As Fumblefingers already [showed in the comments](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=window+into+the+past%2Cwindow+to+the+past&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwindow%20into%20the%20past%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwindow%20to%20the%20past%3B%2Cc0), the usage of *into* is more common.

Since looking into the past has a sense of direction this [blog post from grammar girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/in-to-or-into) might give you the rule you are looking for. Summarizing, use *in* to indicate a position, use *into* when indicating action, direction or motion.

Comment: The OP was asking about *to* versus *into*.